# 'redirect url' for an oAuth2.0 client

Tags: android, rest, oauth-2.0, client

I am extremely new to the OAuth framework and am currently working on writing a client on the android platform.

When trying to register my application with the api provider, it asks for a redirect url. I searched around bit and found some literature that says that it is a security feature to avoid phishing attacks and stuff like that.

I am kind of confused with what I learnt. Practically speaking, as a client developer, how should I go about with the redirect url? Is there a guideline that I need to follow? Does it take arbitrary values?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the redirect URL is to prevent a developer of a malicious website from tricking the OAuth server from generating a token intended for you and giving it to them. The potential vulnerability is:

1. Request to `https://oauth.server.com/login?app_id=2&redirect_uri=https://malicious.com`
2. Upon user logging in, OAuth server generates a token and redirects to `https://malicious.com?token=xxx`

If the above flow works, the malicious server gets a valid token it can then use to interact with your application.

Instead when you register your application they ask for the return URL straight away. This enables them to always redirect to the same URL for your application and therefore always pass the valid token to a known application.

This part of the OAuth flow is covered in [the OAuth 2 spec section 3.1.2 Redirection Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2). There are quite a few rules for it so I won't quote it here.

If you are consuming this token via an API rather than through the OAuth flow then you probably don't need the redirect URL.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot.

Another question, why does the server need to redirect my request in the first place, will this vulnerability still exist if there was no provision for this redirection?

Comment: A standard web application using OAuth will perform a redirect to the OAuth server as per step 1 above when the user tries to log in (e.g. clicks the "Log in with Facebook" button). The OAuth Server will then redirect back with the token. Using this flow, the vulnerability exists. If you're not using this flow, then you don't have the need for the redirect url.